# Calling a function bound to an event from another function bound to an event isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm making a custom editor for slickgrid, although I doubt what I'm doing really matters in this case.  So let's say I have something like this vaguely setup:

```
function TestEditor(args) {
 var $test0, $test1;
 //other variables

 this.init = function () {
  //various init stuff, it all works fine
  //init $test0 and $test1, also works fine

  $test0.bind("change", this.test0Changed);
  $test1.bind("change", this.test1Changed);

  this.test0Changed(); //this works fine too, makes the nested call to test1Changed
 }

 this.test0Changed = function() {
  //does various operations
  this.test1Changed(); //calls test1Changed, this works _unless_ test0Changed is called through an event, then the code breaks here!
  //stuff that won't happen when the code breaks at the previous call
 }

 this.test1Changed = function() {
  //stuff, works fine unless called by test0Changed triggered by an event, then nothing
 }

 //whatever, lots of other stuff, it all works

 this.init();
}
```

I want test0Changed to make a call to test1Changed, and it works fine if I explicitly make the call myself to this.test0Changed() in the code.  But when test0Changed is triggered by the 'change' event, the code breaks when it tries to call this.test1Changed().  If I comment out the call to this.test1Changed(), everything is fine, so I know it's that precise line that is causing the problem.  What is causing this?

Comment: what is the `test` variable noted on the broken line?

Comment: oops, that was dumb, i meant this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you the function to `.bind()`, it doesn't "remember" the intial `this` value.

As a handler, `this` will be the element that received the event.

```
this.init = function () {

   var self = this;

   $test0.bind("change", function() {self.test0Changed.apply(self, arguments);});
   $test1.bind("change", function() {self.test1Changed.apply(self, arguments);});

 }
```

Here I referenced the `this` you want to use in a variable, and I passed anonymous functions  that use that referenced `this` value to call the functions.

---

I also used `.apply` to ensure that all the original arguments are passed on. If that isn't necessary, you could change it to this...

```
this.init = function () {

   var self = this;

   $test0.bind("change", function() {self.test0Changed();});
   $test1.bind("change", function() {self.test1Changed();});

 }
```

---

Or you could use jQuery's `$.proxy` to retain the `this` value...

```
this.init = function () {

   $test0.bind("change", $.proxy(this, 'test0Changed'));
   $test1.bind("change", $.proxy(this, 'test1Changed'));

 }
```

Comment: Oh, is there any way to get this in that context, then?  And to have it work for both kinds of calls?

Comment: Excellent, $.proxy worked fine, although you're missing a closing parenthesis.